# deriving sine half angle formula from sine double angle formula

Tags: trigonometry

I can derive the sin, cos and tan half angle formulas from the cosine double angle formula. But I'm having trouble deriving the sine half angle formula from the sine double angle formula

Below is my attempt at deriving sine half angle formula from sine double angle formula

[image]

And I could go no further.

Could someone provide me with a hint?

Edit 1:

below is the sine half identity I want to derive from sine double angle identity

[image]

Comment: *Which* half-angle formula are you attempting to derive? Also note that when taking square roots you have to consider the $\,\pm\,$ sign choice.

Comment: I'm attempting to derive the sine half angle formula by using sine double angle formula.

Comment: Easier to start with: $$\cos(2y) = \cos^2(y)-\sin^2(y)=1-2\sin^2(y) $$

Comment: @Thor There is no single `sine half angle formula`. You just showed how to derive *one* such formula (though the derivation is not complete, and apparently not what you were after, either). So, to repeat the question from my first comment, *which* half-angle formula are you attempting to derive?

Comment: @DavidPeterson, thanks for the tip. I have already successfully used cosine double angle identities to derive all the half angle identities. I just want to challenge myself by using the sine double angle identity as the starting point.

Comment: The problem is, that you introduced $\cos(y/2)$, so you need the half-angle identity for $\cos$ to continue

Comment: @dxiv please see my updated question. I'm a beginner so please forgive me if my intention is not clear.

Comment: @Thor Then replace the denominator with the similar $\,\cos\,$ half-angle formula and simplify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Square everything:
$$\sin^2 y =4\cos^2(y/2)\sin^2(y/2)=4(1-\sin^2 (y/2))\sin^2(y/2)=4\sin^2(y/2)-4\sin^4(y/2)$$

So
$$
1-\sin^2 y = 1 - 4 \sin^2(y/2)+4\sin^4(y/2)=(1-2 \sin^2 (y/2))^2
$$
That is,
$$
\cos^2 y = (1-2 \sin^2 (y/2))^2$$

Unfortunately this only gives you
$$
\pm \cos y = 1 - 2 \sin^2(y/2)
$$
(the cost of squaring in the first place). But since both sides are smooth, we have to make the same choice of sign everywhere — and at $0$ it clearly is the positive one. So we have showed that:
$$
\cos y = 1 - 2 \sin^2(y/2)
$$
and so
$$
\sin (y/2)=\pm \sqrt{\frac{1-\cos y}{2}}
$$